# Java how to tell I have been to all numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, shortest-path

So I have an Array A of N size containing positive Integers.
the array could have many duplicates, and I want to find the shortest distance to travel the array and visit each number that occurs in the array

what is the best way to iterate the array starting at A[0] and so on.

So far I have come up with adding all the numbers to a set so I can compare if I have been there already.

for example in the following array the shortest distance to visit all numbers is 5

```
Integer[] nums = { 2, 6, 7, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2 };
```

so I add them to a hashset

```
Set<Integer> UniqueNums = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(nums));
```

this is where I get confused
I know the following is wrong and its only psudocode but
i would do something along the lines of

```
int count = 0;
   for(int i : nums )
   {
       if(UniqueNums.contains(i)
       {
       count ++;
       }

   }
```

Comment: That loop will return the length of Array `nums`

Comment: How do you get 5 as shortest distance of all numbers?

Comment: `Set` will remove all duplicates from your array. So you will get a wrong distance.

Comment: How do you define "shortest distance"? It seems you're simply asking for the count of unique numbers (which is these five: `1, 2, 3, 6, 7`), which is `int count = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(nums)).size();`

Comment: Using a HashSet defeats the purpose as @EleazarEnrique mentions. Basically you want to ignore duplicates at the end, but you will still have to travel through duplicates.

Comment: The shortest distance to travel through the array and visit all unique numbers

Comment: Define "travel through the array".

Comment: You can start at any point in the array and move forward and count how many moves it took to reach all unique numbers.

Comment: Moving through a duplicate number would still be a step to a unique number, though?

Comment: So the answer is start at the `6` value and move forward 5 times, traversing `6, 7, 2, 3, 3, 1`? Or same subarray in reverse? But basically, you need to edit the question and clarify what you mean, because it is certainly unclear right now.

Comment: starting at any point in the array changes things, put that in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try this .... It is just a pseudo code.

```
int count = 0;
int i =0;
while(i  < nums.lnegth  && UniqueNums.size() >0)
   {
    UniqueNums.remove (nums[i]);
    i++;
   }

Sysout("minimum length of array containing all unique element  from starting " + i);
```

What i am doing - > After putting unique element to set, I am iterating the array and started removing element which i visited in nums.
when i have visited all unique element in nums at that time "UniqueNums" will be empty and it will terminate the loop

Comment: Yes basically that but I need to repeat that starting at index 1 then 2 and so on, store the cont values in a list and then get the smallest one. Thanks you have pointed me in the right direction anyway.